# regular expression to mask all but the last 4 digits of a credit card with dashes, spaces, and leading number

Tags: regex

I am looking for the EXPERT help with a regular expression to mask all credit card numbers but leave the last 4 digits. I found a few site on here that relevant but doesn't remove dashes/spaces. For example:

----original-----
Visa 4263982640269299
4263982640269299
4263 9826 4026 9299
4263-9826-4026-9299
5263-9826-4026-9299
5263982640269299
5263 9826 4026 9299
----expected result----
Visa xxxxxxxxxxxx9299 (don't want to relace the leading word(s))
xxxxxxxxxxxx9299
xxxxxxxxxxxx9299
xxxxxxxxxxxx9299

not match b/c leading number is not 4
Visa 5263-9826-4026-9299
5263982640269299
5263 9826 4026 9299
I have tried a few but this come near but don't know how to exclude the last 4:

\b4\d(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}

Thanks everyone in advance for your help!

Comment: Does your card number have only 16 digits or can be more or less than that, as in your sample data, I saw some samples where it is less and more. What behavior you want there?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi - thank you for your reply. I am targeting different credit cards from different companies. I think some credit cards are between 13-19. https://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html#cardFormats

Answer (score 3):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure that there are at least 4 non-alphabet characters ahead a matching character, and use a negative lookahead pattern with nested positive lookbehind to avoid matching a space right after an alphabet:

```
(?!(?<=[A-Z])\s)[^A-Z](?=[^A-Z\n]{4,})
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/155

Comment: blhsing - Thank you very much. I have updated my description a little more sorry. your suggestion is so close but it remove the word VISA as well. Also, I want to start with a leading number after the word VISA or other word(s) in front of it. I have tried \b4\d(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16} but it doesn't exclude the last 4. regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/152 and https://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/153

Comment: how to query to target the leading number? like ^4  or ^3 : like these except they don't exclude the last for digits. ^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?
 |  (?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}
 | 222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}
 |  3[47][0-9]{13}
 |  3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}
 |  6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}
 |  (?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}
)$         Just target maybe number for this example doesn't have to target the rest of the numbers in my regex101 as long as it capture a leading number (^4) spaces and dashes

Answer (score 0):

i have final found an answer to my question - thanks all for your help!